# exif_imagetype() in if-statement

Tags: php, function

I need to identify the filetype of an image using `exif_imagetype()`.

This is my code:

```
$imgSrc = "image.jpg";

    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
       $filetype = 'The picture is GIF';
    }
    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $filetype = 'The picture is JPEG';
    }
    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $filetype = 'The picture is PNG';
    }
    echo $filetype;
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that `$filetype` does not only echo the string I wanted but it also echo's (what I think is) the complete result of the `exif_imagetype()`

Part of the output:

```
The picture is JPEG����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG 
v80), default quality ��C      $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82
<.342��C     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��
```

As you can see it does echo my string but I don't know why the rest of this is in the output.

Can anyone tell my why this happens?
Thanks in advance.

> Edit: Complete php page added below

```
//getting the image dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

    //check file type + saving the image into memory
    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
       $filetype = 'The picture is GIF';
       $myImage = imagecreatefromgif($imgSrc);
    }
    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $filetype = 'The picture is JPEG';
        $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
    }
    if (exif_imagetype($imgSrc) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $filetype ='The picture is PNG';
        $myImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgSrc);
    }

// calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
if ($width > $height) {
  $y = 0;
  $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $height;
} else {
  $x = 0;
  $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $width;
}

//read EXIF header from uploaded file
$exif = exif_read_data($imgSrc);

//fix the Orientation if EXIF data exist
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $myImage = imagerotate($myImage,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $myImage = imagerotate($myImage,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $myImage = imagerotate($myImage,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}

// copying the part into thumbnail
$thumbSize = 200;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

//final output
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: Is this all the code you are showing? Because this code works perfectly on my enivronment.

Comment: What browser are you using? or are you trying to get the output from console? because this still work fine for me in browser with Chrome.
The thing is that with header() you are saying to browser that "now comes image, read this as image file"

Comment: @SiimKallari I didn't add the complete code because I thought adding that part was causing the problem. I added the complete page in my post now.

Comment: I test the code both with Chrome and Safari. I tried removing the header() but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: how big is is the image file? i remember reading something tat low weight files can bug out, try to use something that is atleast 20kb

Comment: first files were under 20kb, tested one of 45kb but still no difference...